# ERROR : Starting cassandra database using CassandraDaemon

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am trying to start cassandra daemon from java and i am using the following the code

## JAVA CODE :

```
        CassandraDaemon cassandraDaemon;
        System.setProperty("cassandra.config", "file:/Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml");
        System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", "file:/Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/resources/cassandra/conf/log4j-server.properties");
        System.setProperty("storage-config", "/Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/resources/cassandra/conf/");
        System.setProperty("cassandra-foreground", "true");
        cassandraDaemon = new CassandraDaemon();
        cassandraDaemon.init(null);
        cassandraThread.setDaemon(true);
        cassandraThread.start();
```

## EXCEPTION :

```
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@1a42752a; Unable to find property 'batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
in "<reader>", line 10, column 1:
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
^


at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:372)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:177)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:136)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:122)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Loader.load(Loader.java:52)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:166)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadYaml(DatabaseDescriptor.java:147)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:122)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:150)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.init(CassandraDaemon.java:311)
at com.code4reference.gradle.Cassandrautil.start(Cassandrautil.java:101)
at com.code4reference.gradle.Cassandrautil$start.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at com.code4reference.gradle.Code4ReferencePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(Code4ReferencePlugin.groovy:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:499)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:480)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:93)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:70)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@1a42752a; Unable to find property 'batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:305)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:184)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:370)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:342)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:240)
    ... 109 more
null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@1a42752a; Unable to find property 'batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
Invalid yaml; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been stopped, killed or may have crashed)
5:16:21 PM: External task execution finished 'start'.

## DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT :

I am using data stax cassandra version 4.5.0 and using apaache cassandra driver for starting database .

Please suggest solution for my issue ?

Thanks,
Muthu Selvan SR

Answer (score 1):

It's a versioning problem. batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb was added in Cassandra 1.2, which means the JAR that your are using is for <= 1.1. Check your classpath and make sure you have only the JARs for the version you want.

Comment: Thanks richard , Already i set the $CASSANDRA_HOME=/Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0 is referring latest version of cassandra , should i set any thing else before running my code , please advice !

Comment: CASSANDRA_HOME doesn't help since you're running it from your own code. What is your classpath?

Comment: export CLASSPATH=/Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/lib , i just exported the CLASSPATH using the above command and i ran the command but still get the same error , do you want me set any thing else in CLASSPATH , please advice !     I have reffered the url :http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cassandra and ran "cassandra.in.sh" but still the error is coming

Comment: It's much safer to set the classpath using the -cp arg. You need to check which your classpath for different versions of cassandra. Also, that link is for Cassandra 1.0 but the DSE version you are using is for Cassandra 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your update , i have updated -cp of the cassandra /Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/lib dnd i ran the shell script which is in /Users/mselv2/dse/dse-4.5.0/bin/dse-env.sh but i am getting the same error , Could you please help what is exactly classpath variable is required to set for running my code ?